# Make div with sessionStorage data auto-update as data changes, not on page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage, session-storage

I'm trying to build something analogous to a shopping cart. On the page, a user can click any number of `inventory` items, upon click, these items get added to `sessionStorage`. On a different part of the page, I then show the `sessionStorage` so that the user can modify the cart as needed.

Right now I have a problem where the `sessionStorage` works in that it has all the data, but if I click a bunch of items, it's not until I refresh the page that I see the data reflected in my cart. This defeats the entire purpose of me trying to learn Javascript, so hoping there's an answer to allow auto-updates so a user can add to/remove from cart without page refreshes.

**Code:**

```
<body>
  <div class="col-xs-2" id="cart">
  </div>
</body>

<script>
  var cart = [];
    $(document).on("click", "#inventory", function() { 

      //if statement so that it pushes ONLY if it doesn't already exist in cart
      cart.push({
        inventory_id: $(this).data('inventory_id'),
        inventory_name: $(this).data('inventory_name'),
        inventory_description: $(this).data('inventory_description'),
        lender_email: $(this).data('lender_email')
      });
      sessionStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(cart));
    });

  $('#cart').html(sessionStorage.getItem("cart"));
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to get the current state of the cart items so you can append on it, Otherwise you're replacing the same item.

You can view it live here: http://jsfiddle.net/1vfo2e0g/4/

### HTML

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="item" 
    data-inventory_id="1" 
    data-inventory_name="Item 1" 
    data-inventory_description="Description 1" 
    data-lender_email="email1@email.com">Item 1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="item" 
    data-inventory_id="2" 
    data-inventory_name="Item 2" 
    data-inventory_description="Description 2" 
    data-lender_email="email2@email.com">Item 2</a>
  </li>
<ul>

 <div class="col-xs-2" id="cart">
    <ul></ul>
 </div>
```

### JS

```
populateCart(); // Populates the cart when page loads

$(document).on("click", ".item", function() { 

      // Get current state of our items from session
      var items = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("cart"));
      if(items === null) // if cart is empty
          items = [];

      // Populate the item
      var item = {
        inventory_id: $(this).data('inventory_id'),
        inventory_name: $(this).data('inventory_name'),
        inventory_description: $(this).data('inventory_description'),
        lender_email: $(this).data('lender_email')
      };
      items.push(item); // Push item to the cart
      sessionStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(items)); // Save cart back to session
      addToCart(item); // append item to the cart

    });



function populateCart(){
  var items = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("cart"));
    if(items !== null){
       var cart = $('#cart > ul');
       for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
         cart.append('<li>' + items[i]['inventory_name'] + "</li>");
       }
    }
}

function addToCart(item){
  $('#cart > ul').append('<li>'+ item['inventory_name'] +'</li>');
}
```

Comment: This is GREAT! It works wonderfully, just to confirm my understanding, it seems to me though that instead of `populateCart` and `addToCart`, you can just have `populateCart` if it runs not only when the page loads. Is that right?

Comment: Did you see it [live](http://jsfiddle.net/1vfo2e0g/4/)? 
The reason for `addToCart` is to avoid fetching and parsing all the items from _session_, since we already have `var item =` we can just append it to `cart > ul`

Comment: By the way @Ervald, I'm trying to now do the opposite, i.e., a remove, but although the remove works, it still requires a page refresh. And i followed your suggestion and updated not only the `cart` in sessionStorage, but also made a `removeFromCart` function that uses jquery `remove` on the `li` item. Any thoughts?

Comment: Here's a way how you can remove items [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1vfo2e0g/8/). I'd suggest you used AngularJs for building a cart system.

Comment: Perfect! Just one minor tweak, `$(this).parent().remove()` should just be `$(this).remove()`. Yes I've been suggested both Angular and Backbone. The challenge is that I literally thought I could do this in pure Rails and had to pick up JS just for this... so I'm stumbling a lot and I think it would be even harder if I had to pick up a framework as well...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59894/discussion-between-ervald-and-james).